# jquery change css on radiobutton checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

below i have my fiddle which i want to change the text color when the radio button is selected. However i cant get it to work. at the moment it isnt firing at all and i cant get the div css to change.

```
$(".package-container").click(function () {
   $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('.package-title').removeClass('highlight');
   $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
   $(this).find('.package-title').addClass('highlight');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46jGT/3/

**EDIT**
Thanks, it does work with the JSFiddle, but in my .net project i cant get this peice to work. i have jquery 1.9 referenced at the bottom on the master page with this code on the control page.

Comment: it works. just add jquery library. http://jsfiddle.net/46jGT/5/

Comment: [**Working JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/46jGT/6/)

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work inside my aspx project, does anyone know why? i have jquery referenced at the top etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you're missing the `jquery` library. Your code is [working](http://jsfiddle.net/46jGT/6/) fine as it is once the library is added

Comment: thanks, i have got the jquery library refrenced in my .net project inside of the master page, but this doesnt work still, would you know why?